# When a button is clicked, a prompt comes up and ask user for input, input (email) gets appended to the end of a predefined link. How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies for a long title, I'm a beginner but what I want to achieve should be pretty simple to do, I think :)

I have a button on my website that points to a link, let's say mysite.com/abc=$userid
Once the button is clicked the prompt should open up and ask the user for their email address. After they input and press ok/submit I'd like to take their input and replace $userid with it e.g. mysite.com/abc=john@mail.com and open this link in a new tab.

Hope the question makes sense and I'd be eternally grateful for any tips on how to achieve this. Please help.

Kind regards,
Jack Dunn

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Each individual piece of logic you've described is something for which you can find examples online.  Prompting the user for a value, replacing part of a string, opening a new tab/window, etc.  What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: This is not a great place to ask this type of question (on Stack Overflow). Try searching for a tutorial on jquery and forms

Answer (score 1):

Quick jquery solution as this answer is marked with jQuery tag :

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var email = prompt('Please enter your email');
    if (email != null) {
        location.href = location.href + "?abc=" + email
    }
});
```